Qt получение значения ползунка(Qslider)
У меня есть класс в котором происходит отрисовка изображения и эта отрисовка зависит от одной переменной в классе
Также есть ползунок (Qslider) из которого мы должны получить значение и присвоить его к значению из класса.
Как это можно реализовать?
То есть как можно получить значение из Qslider и записать это значение в переменную?
Заранее большое спасибо!

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#value-prop / https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#valueChanged
